# Convert string to new Date object in UTC timeZONE

Tags: javascript, extjs

Can anyone let me know how to convert a `string` to a `date` Object with UTC time zone in ExtJs?

String is `"2015-10-07T23:59:00"`. I would like to get the same in Date Object without changing the timezone.

Comment: Append the `Z` timezone stamp on the end and the parser will know the zone `"2015-10-07T23:59:00Z"`. If you're working with the native _Date_ make sure you use the _UTC methods_ thereafter too

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your date string does not have a timezone.

When you make a JavaScript date object from a string, there are two possible outcomes you could expect:

- You may want the date to be 23:59 Local (23:59 CEST in my case).
  In this case, you want to use `new Date("2015-10-07 23:59:00")` with plain javascript (note the missing `T`), or `Ext.Date.parse("2015-10-07T23:59:00","c");`.
- You may want the date to be 23:59 UTC (e.g. 01:59 CEST).
  In this case, you want to use `new Date("2015-10-07T23:59:00")`.

Of course, whenever you output the date, you have to get the date in the correct time zone as well. The console/toString will usually show it in local time. JavaScript does provide `getUTC...` methods if you require other time zones.

You see, using Time Zones with JavaScript is a painful experience. I would recommend to try moment.js if you need full time zone support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ext.Date.parse`.It gives **Date Object** as output.It syntax is:

```
Ext.Date.parse( String input, String format, [Boolean strict] )
```

For Example:

```
Ext.Date.parse("2015-10-07T23:59:00", "Y-m-dTH:i:s");
```

Comment: Did you give the same input

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var millisFromEpoch = Date.parse('2015-10-07T23:59:00');
```

it will parse date in GMT timezone, Ext.date.parse use the current timezone instead

Comment: Yeah I tried..but changing the above time to gmt gives "2015-10-08 00:00:00"...I want it to be in same timezone..